# The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts after Set_express_checkout

Tags: paypal

After getting token from Set_express_checkout, when I process Do_express_checkout_payment its show

```
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => EUR
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 15.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 10.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 5.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 0.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT] => 0.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED] => false
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME] => Ahsan Zahid
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] => House 17-18,Road 1,Block New C
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => Midland
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE] => MI
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] => 48642
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => United States
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSNORMALIZATIONSTATUS] => None
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Bid Shopping Total Payable
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0] => 0.00
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 10.00
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => Total Number of Item 1
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0] =>    0.00000
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0] =>    0.00000
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0] =>    0.00000
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0] =>    0.00000
```

> Error code 10413
>   Error The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.

Please help..

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct request log?  What you're showing here wouldn't trigger that error.  Maybe this was your SetExpressCheckout request..??  I can't see the METHOD parameter so it seems this is an incomplete sample.

Comment: Dear i know it's confusing perhaps you can visit this link http://systechprojects.com/projects/bidtv/payments_pro/Set_express_checkout

Comment: You can have a look in the code [http://pasted.co/3e43f929](http://pasted.co/3e43f929)

Comment: Actually, you're using my class library for PayPal, so it's not confusing at all.  It's just that the request log you've shown here would not cause that error.  The code you're showing is for SetExpressCheckout but as you said, that call is working fine.  It's your DoExpressCheckoutPayment request that is failing.  That's what we need to review, and you just need to make sure it's setup the same way your SEC request is and it will work.

Comment: Dear @AndrewAngell thanks for the point 'setup the same way your SEC'. I forget to set 'shippingamt' => $checkoutDetails['SHIPPINGAMT'].